# What is analog in Serilog WriteTo.Console(new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter()) for appsettings.json file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I am trying to do same things like `loggerConfigBuilder.WriteTo.Console(new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter());` in appsettings.json file but i don't know and can't find any notation for it. Do you know how can i use provide this option in appsettings.json? Now it is like

```
 "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
 "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
              "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.RenderedCompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
            }
          },
    ]
```